# Cakephp, connect the database to the webpage

Tags: database, cakephp

While connecting to database in cakephp am getting following notice and warning:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: homepage [APP/Template\Pages\home.ctp, line 180]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\Pages\home.ctp, line 180]
```

I have met this problem for displaying data from database.

**Edit** here is my controller

```
public function home() { 
   $homepage = $this->paginate($this->Pages); 
   $this->set(compact('homepage')); 
}
```

Comment: public function home()
    {
        $homepage = $this->paginate($this->Pages);

        $this->set(compact('homepage'));

    }    here is my controller

Comment: Check your routing. Is `/pages/home` actually being handled by the `home` function?